# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [14] unable to open database file'

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

So I'm making a website for a client that uses a SQLite Database and PHP to display information in a Table on one of the pages of the site. When running the page I get this error. From what I understand it's caused by the database and/or directory to the database not having the correct permissions to access it. I'm working on a Charter Business Server and from what I can tell, I have the correct permissions set. I've tried Googling the issue but found nothing that has helped.

Here is the PHP code:

```
 <?php ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    $dir = 'sqlite:/HTML/fsrd2.com/database/fsrd.db';
    $database = new PDO($dir) or die("<tr><td>Cannot Open</td></tr>");
    $query = "SELECT * FROM projects";
    foreach($database->query($query) as $row)
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
  ?>
```

And here is the full error message:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [14] unable to open database file' in /var/www/vhosts/12/234028/webspace/httpdocs/fsrd2.com/fsrd_projects.php:50 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/vhosts/12/234028/webspace/httpdocs/fsrd2.com/fsrd_projects.php(50): PDO->__construct('sqlite:/HTTP/fs...') #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/vhosts/12/234028/webspace/httpdocs/fsrd2.com/fsrd_projects.php on line 50
```

Comment: I'd guess this has something to do with escaping your slashes, or permissions.

Comment: Escaping my slashes?

Comment: `/HTML/fsrd2.com/database/fsrd.db` is an absolute path. Unless there really is an `HTML/` directory in your system's root dir (which would be very unusual), you probably wanted a path relative to your script (i.e. without the `/` at the beginning).

Comment: I have tried the following:
`/fsrd2.com/database/fsrd.db`
`fsrd2.com/database/fsrd.db`
`HTML/fsrd2.com/database/fsrd.db`
None of these seemed to change the resulting error. I believe read permissions have been set on the file and folder but I don't know how to check.

Comment: For anyone reading this, make sure the directory in which the sqlite file is, also is writable (and maybe executable?) for the php user.